# Bluetooth stops working often

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

It's been a while since I had this trouble. Basically, I use my bluetooth headphones (Sony WH-CH510) exclusively with my laptop, that has Ubuntu 23.04 as distro (but I had this trouble with other versions of the same OS as well). Sometimes out of the blue the headphones go in pairing mode, the audio isn't transmitted anymore and I can't disconnect them. Then, when I reboot the laptop, the bluetooth can't be activated (in the sense that it disappears from the shortcuts in the top-right corner, and the radio button in the settings is permanently turned off, with no possibilities to click it). I tried many solutions, asked to many communities (often they said that the bluetooth card was burned or something), tried to resolve it by myself, but nothing.
Then, after few days (usually a period that goes from 2 days to a week) the bluetooth returns available.

This is the output of `systemctl status bluetooth`

```
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

giu 11 14:36:11 Computer-ricky systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).
```

I have no idea how to reactivate it, and I'm pretty tired to wait days.
Also, when it deactivates in Ubuntu, it stops working also in Windows.

If you need something else, just ask. I'll edit the questions with the necessary data as soon as possible

Comment: Must be something wrong with the headset if they suddenly go into pairing mode on their own

Comment: Could be, but I have just this one. I'd need a way to resolve that

Answer (score 0):

> "Also, when it deactivates in Ubuntu, it stops working also in
> Windows."

you can try to cut the power to your laptop forcefully, if your laptop is newer one which we can't take off the battery anymore usually there is a tiny hole in the back of your laptop, poke and hold there i say maybe 15s and try to turn it on again.

were `sudo systemctl start bluetooth` doesnt work ?

Comment: There is no such hole. I could try to disassemble the bottom shell, but I would probably cause other troubles, so better not. `systemctl start bluetooth` does absolutely nothing. Any other solution?

Comment: do you have fast startup enabled in windows ? if so, try to turn it off, then shutdown, wait maybe 5min, turn it on again. maybe it will pickup your bt devices

Comment: no fast startup, i disabled it many years ago